# .vimrc is not properly loaded when running sudoedit or sudo -e vim

Tags: vimrc

I have a very strange issue. I am running vim on my Centos 7 box and having issues getting it to load my .vimrc when I run `sudoedit` or `ssh -e vim`.

When I run sudoedit I end up with a few of my settings carrying over but none of my custom colors or any of my key mappings transfer over.

I do see line numbers and I think my indentation settings are working, but not much else.

---

Here you can see what it looks like normally:

[image: Called as vim]

Here is what it looks like when using `sudoedit`:

[image: Called with sudoedit]

I included my `:version` output just to show it's not calling vi or some other version of the editor, and it clearly shows that both are calling the same .vimrc file. It's just that one is actually reading it and the other isn't...

Comment: One output says the system `vimrc` file is `/etc/virc` and the other says its `/etc/vimrc`. What happens if you run `EDITOR=vim sudoedit`?

Comment: Declaring the EDITOR variable before running sudoedit seems to work. However I'm not sure why it doesn't read the environment variable that I declared in my .bashrc

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Setting EDITOR in the same line as sudoedit works for me too, but I don't understand why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `sudoedit` or `sudo -e`, sudo will start the editor defined by the environment variables `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` (in that order) or will typically fall back to `vi`.

In your screenshots, you can see that two different versions of Vim are called.
`vim` calls a "Huge version without gui", while `sudoedit` calls a "Small version without gui". Most likely the "Small version..." is called when you invoke `vi`. The small version does not include syntax highlighting. See `:help +feature-list`.

By setting `EDITOR=vim` you tell `sudo`, that it should start `vim`. Hence you get the full feature set.

Whether `vi` and `vim` starts different executables is installation dependent. On my machine they both start the same version of Vim.